# Jqgrid edit mode edittype text shows unwanted tags

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

while using jqgrid with editUrl, in edit mode, (when I click on edit button)
it shows unwanted tag like "INPUT style="WIDTH: 98%" id=....."

How to get ride of this & display only the value inside the textbox.

The code I am using is as follows.

```
    jQuery("#myGrid").jqGrid({
        pager: jQuery('#myGridPager'),
        sortname: 'Name',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 50],
        sortorder: "asc",
        height: "auto",
        autowidth: true,
        colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Dept', 'Status', 'ParentNodeName'],
        colModel: [
          { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', hidden: true, key : true },
          { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 200, editable: true, edittype: "text", editrules: { required: true} },
          { name: 'Dept', index: 'Dept', width: 90, editable: true, editrules: { required: true} },
          { name: 'Status', index: 'Status', width: 25, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "A:Active;I:Inactive"} },
          { name: 'ParentNodeName',
                    index: 'ParentNodeName',
                    editable: true,
                    edittype: "select",
                    editoptions: { dataUrl: "/MyEntity/GetMyEntitys" }
                },
          ], 
        datatype: 'json',
        viewrecords: true,
        mtype: 'GET',
        jsonReader: {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            userdata: "userdata"
        },
        url: "/MyEntity/GetMyEntitysData",
        multiselect: false,
        editurl: "/MyEntity/EditMyEntity?__SESSIONKEY=<%=Model.SessionKey %>",
        caption: "Data Entry"
    })
    .navGrid('#myGridPager', { view: true, del: true, add: true, edit: true },
    { height: 150, reloadAfterSubmit: false, modal: true }, // default settings for edit
    { height: 150, reloadAfterSubmit: true, modal: true, url: "/MyEntity/AddMyEntity?__SESSIONKEY=<%=Model.SessionKey %>" }, //  settings for add
    { height: "auto", reloadAfterSubmit: false, modal: true, url: "/MyEntity/DeleteMyEntity?__SESSIONKEY=<%=Model.SessionKey %>" }, // delete 
    { closeOnEscape: true, multipleSearch: true, closeAfterSearch: true }, // search options
    {} /* view parameters*/
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue following code pattern is used:
We are changing (making false) editable property when edit dialog box is displayed; and turning it true when the dialog box is closed. This way the value can be edited only in edit dialog box and not in grid. 
But this code is resolving the issue of unwanted tag as well.

```
.navGrid('#' + myGridPager, { view: false, del: true, add: true, edit: true },
{    //Edit options
    height: 200,
    reloadAfterSubmit: true,
    modal: true,
    viewPagerButtons: false,
    closeAfterEdit: true,
    closeOnEscape: true,
    url: "MyEntity/EditMyEntity?__SESSIONKEY=<%=Model.SessionKey %>",
    beforeInitData: function (formId) {
        var cpr = bagrid.jqGrid('getColProp', 'Name');
        cpr.editable = true;

    },
    onClose: function () {
        var cpr = bagrid.jqGrid('getColProp', 'Name');
        cpr.editable = false;
    }
},
```

.....

the column properties can be changed for edit,add or delete mode as shown above. We can hide or unhide columns in grid or dialogbox using this code pattern.